# Updating my Wordpress.org version will cause my site to break... What can I do to avoid this?

Tags: child-theme, updates

I created this website for a relative years ago. I'm a noob and not a web developer so I stupidly customized the theme I'm using without creating a child theme. I read that a child theme will cause the site to not break.

I've never once updated it since creating it and my relative has just noticed and wants to be able to update everything as soon as possible.

I know updating it will end up breaking the website.

What can I do to sort out this problem? Do I turn it into a child theme? I don't have a clue how to do that. I'm such a noob. :( Please help!!

Is it possible I can actually turn it into a child theme or is it too late to do that now I've already made huge adjustments to the original theme? I'd love to know if I can do this or if there are any good guides to follow if so. I see there are lots of tutorials online on how to create child themes, but only at the start, not once everything has been customised...

Answer (score 1):

As you have figured out, 'child themes' are very beneficial. Not updating - not a good thing.

If you have any programming skills, then you could create a child theme. (Lots of tutorials on how to do that.) Then take any page that you modified in the main theme and place them in the same folder structure in your child theme area. That should override the main theme.

Then update the main theme, and any plugins.

Note that updating the WP 'core' (and you should, based on recent hacks) should not affect the changes you made to your current theme.

Another alternative is to temporarily activate a new theme, then work on the child theme process for your current theme. You could also place a copy of your current theme in a different (new) folder, change the theme heading (inside the theme code) for a different name, and then activate that temp copy.

Overall, though, this is a cautionary tale about the importance of not modifying core code or themes, but to use child themes. If any of this is above your knowledge/comfort level, you may need to ask for some ($) help.